# Error: invalid BigNumber value (argument="value", value=undefined during a exactOutputSingle swap

Tags: uniswap, nodejs, error, swaps, uniswapv3

I'm facing a problem who's driving me crazy

I'm trying to create a swap with this code :

```js
my_tx = await routerV3.exactOutputSingle({
        tokenIn: '0xB4FBF271143F4FBf7B91A5ded31805e42b2208d6',
        tokenOut: '0x1f9840a85d5aF5bf1D1762F925BDADdC4201F984',
        fee: 3000,
        recipient: '0xc9391458c806d8906c8a67e7d9b868cb703a50cf',
        amountOut: 100000000000000,
        amountInMaximum: 70680341863192,
        sqrtPriceLimitX96: 0
    }, 
    {
        value: ethers.BigNumber.from(1000000),
        gasLimit: tx.gasLimit,
        maxFeePerGas: 50000000000,
        maxPriorityFeePerGas: 5000000000,
        type: 2
    });
```

And I'm facing this error :

```
Error: invalid BigNumber value (argument="value", value=undefined, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=bignumber/5.7.0)
    at Logger.makeError (/Users/tsarbuig/JsProjects/test/node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/lib/index.js:238:21)
    at Logger.throwError (/Users/tsarbuig/JsProjects/test/node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/lib/index.js:247:20)
    at Logger.throwArgumentError (/Users/tsarbuig/JsProjects/test/node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/lib/index.js:250:21)
    at Function.BigNumber.from (/Users/tsarbuig/JsProjects/test/node_modules/@ethersproject/bignumber/lib/bignumber.js:239:23)
    at NumberCoder.encode (/Users/tsarbuig/JsProjects/test/node_modules/@ethersproject/abi/lib/coders/number.js:36:39)
    at /Users/tsarbuig/JsProjects/test/node_modules/@ethersproject/abi/lib/coders/array.js:74:19
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at pack (/Users/tsarbuig/JsProjects/test/node_modules/@ethersproject/abi/lib/coders/array.js:60:12)
    at TupleCoder.encode (/Users/tsarbuig/JsProjects/test/node_modules/@ethersproject/abi/lib/coders/tuple.js:71:33)
    at /Users/tsarbuig/JsProjects/test/node_modules/@ethersproject/abi/lib/coders/array.js:74:19 {
  reason: 'invalid BigNumber value',
  code: 'INVALID_ARGUMENT',
  argument: 'value',
  value: undefined
}
```

As you can see:

- I entered a value
- but it's not recognized...

It's crazy because same code with exactInputSingle works perfectly...

Anyone has an idea why the value I enter in my swap is not recognized ?

Thanks a lot guys

Comment: To fix this, you need to wrap the value in an ethers.BigNumber object like this:      ```value: ethers.BigNumber.from('1000000'),```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes getting the correct format for ethers can be tough.

Two things to try:

Try using a string in the bignumber conversion ie `ethers.BigNumber.from('1000000')`

or

Try importing Bignumber separately

```
import { ethers, BigNumber } from "ethers";
BigNumber.from("1000000")
```

and I believe ethers also requires the gasLimit, maxFeePerGas, and maxPriorityFeePerGas will need to be BN as well